# How to get organizer_id value for eventbrite api

Tags: php, api, eventbrite

does anyone know how I go about into finding my organizer_id. I'm trying to use their API http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/ for organizer_list_events but the paramter is a organizer_id which I cannot find in their site. Any help would be great. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide ID of organizer you are going to fetch. You can get list of organizers from http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_organizers/ ex. `<id>65739440</id>`